# Which 2-letter POSIX command is different from all the others?

Tags: shell, command, cd-command, command-names

I was interviewed for an internship and I got the same question as this one: http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Which-2-letter-POSIX-command-is-different-from-all-the-others-QTN_498236.htm

The answer is right, it is `cd` (as the interviewer told me so). I am very confused at this one. Why `cd` is different? I told the interviewer that it is different because it might not be implemented by the "shell", but I did not know what I was talking about at that time.

Comment: I believe `cd` __must__ be implemented by the shell.

Comment: @casey yeah I know, I must be very stupid when I answer this question. I just didn't know what to say at that moment.

Comment: Don't beat yourself up over this Q. It's a dumb Q, it needs to be qualified..."different how"? At any rate knowing this info as a new hire, matters why? This is another example of Unix elitists showing off and making themselves feel superior b/c they know some nonsense-less, useless bit of knowledge.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is of course a subjective question with many plausible answers.

A peculiarity of `cd` is that it has to be implemented by the shell itself: it cannot be an external command (one that runs in a separate program). `cd` changes the working directory of the shell process, and only the shell itself can do that.

This is a poor question because `cd` isn't the only such command. `bg`, `fc`, `fg` are in the same boat. `cd` existed before the others, which is one way to make it unique.

Another plausible answer would be [`dd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29), which has an option syntax that is entirely unlike any other command (it was borrowed from IBM).

Of course you can make arguments for many other commands, such as `rm` (the only 2-letter command that is purely destructive), `su` (the only two-letter command that absolutely has to be setuid root), `at` (the only two-letter command that is typically setgid), `sh` (it's the shell itself, which makes it different from the other commands which are special-purpose), `ps` (the two-letter command that varies the most between unices), etc.